# If I were to have or If I should have

Tags: meaning, expressions, differences, synonyms, word-usage

I am not native English. My question regards the conditional form of the verb have to, must. I was wondering if I could use in interchangeable way the expressions "If I were to have" and "If I should have" and "If I would have".
Thank you for your help.
Massi

Comment: You can look at how the different constructions are used thanks to the Ngram tool https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+I+would+have%2Cif+I+had+had%2Cif+I+should+have%2Cif+I%27d+had%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20would%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20had%20had%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20should%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20%27d%20had%3B%2Cc0 just click on the results below. Hope this helps. PS you need to refresh the blue tab *search lots of books* to see the chart.

Comment: I left out the "if I were (to)" construct because it is by far the most common, and SQUASHED the others in comparison.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest perhaps to address specific examples:

1. "If I had arrived before 5:00, I would have gotten an ocean view room"
2. "If I were to have arrived before 5:00, ..."

The previous two sentences mean the same to me, with (1) seeming more natural. (2) seems somewhat formal.

3. "If I should (would) have arrived before 5:00, ..."

For some speakers, sentence (3) could potentially mean the same as the previous two, but could be viewed as grammatically incorrect by many. The "should" construction does have another use that the other two lack.

- "You should have arrived before 5:00!"
- "If I should have arrived before 5:00, then why didn't you tell me!"

In common speech or contemporary writing I would expect only (1). Do these examples reflect the usage you were thinking of?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I was wondering exactly the correct usage of the three expressions. I have always used the form "should" and a few days ago a my friend used the other one "were to". I was curious to know if they were similar or if each of them required a specific use according with the context. I know now that the more common form is probably the first one with "would have". Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

"If I were" is the subjunctive which is used only in the US, never in Britain.  "If I should" sounds much more to me like a British construction than American.  Perhaps then the basis should be, which side of the Atlantic did the speaker hail from?

Comment: "If I were a rich man" is heard in the UK, as much as "If I was a rich man". See [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+I+were+a%2C+if+I+was+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20were%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20was%20a%3B%2Cc0) which shows the British English corpus